# How to override the Devise lockable warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Ruby on rails app using Devise for authentication. Successfully added lockable devise module, migrations, etc. However, I want the user to be given a warning when they are one attempt away from being locked out and when they are locked out. What is the best strategy for implementing this without interfering too much with devise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise should add the field `failed_attempts` to your model.

You could check that field for the user on Devise's redirect and insert your own flash message if you'd like.  See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated